# Cleanup Function is not running in useEffect in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

I have two dispatch actions 1. fetchHomepage and 2. removeHomepage. I want to run removeHomepage action when I click other link on header menu. So I added removeHomepage in Cleanup Function in useEffect but my cleanup function is not running. When I change something and save then it runs. I am using Redux in this React project. Please can anybody help me out.

HEADER COMPONENT -

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./header.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  fetchHomepage,
  removeHomepage,
} from "../../redux/actions/HomepageActions";
import { setBgColor } from "../../redux/actions/HomepageActions";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Skeleton from "../other/skeletons/Skeleton";

const Header = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.homepageReducer.isLoading);
  const header = useSelector((state) => state.homepageReducer.data.navLinks);
  const bgColor = useSelector((state) => state.homepageReducer.bgColor);
  const { bgColour, borderColor, iconColor } = bgColor;
  const product = useSelector((state) => state.addToCartReducer.products);

  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const location = pathname;

  console.log("component loaded");
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useffect ran");

    const changeNavBg = (bgColor) => {
      if (window.scrollY > 0) {
        dispatch(setBgColor(bgColor));
      } else {
        dispatch(
          setBgColor({
            bgColour: "bg-transparent",
            borderColor: "",
            iconColor: "",
          })
        );
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      changeNavBg({
        bgColour: "bg-black",
        borderColor: "border-white",
        iconColor: "text-white",
      });
    });

    dispatch(fetchHomepage());
    return () => {
      console.log("cleanup function ran");
      dispatch(removeHomepage());
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeNavBg);
    };
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Skeleton header={"header"} />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>HEADER</h1>
      {
        <div className="dvHeader">
          <nav
            className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg ${bgColour} ${
              location !== "/" ? "bg-black" : ""
            } navbar-light fixed-top`}
          >
            <div className="container">
              <div>
                <button
                  className="navbar-toggler"
                  type="button"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#slideDownMenu"
                  aria-controls="slideDownMenu"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                  <span className="">
                    <i
                      className={`fa fa-bars ${iconColor} ${
                        location !== "/" ? "text-white" : ""
                      } `}
                    ></i>
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="order-lg-0">
                <Link to="/">
                  <img
                    width="50"
                    src={header && header.logo.url}
                    className="img-fluid"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="order-lg-2 d-lg-none">
                <span
                  className="d-flex"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#mobileCartModal"
                >
                  <span className="d-inline-block mr-1">
                    <i
                      className={`fa fa-shopping-cart ${iconColor} ${
                        location !== "/" ? "text-white" : ""
                      } `}
                    ></i>
                  </span>
                  <span
                    className={`d-inline-block ${iconColor} ${
                      location !== "/" ? "text-white" : ""
                    } `}
                  >
                    {product.length}
                  </span>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div
                className="collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-1"
                id="slideDownMenu"
              >
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto px-3">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/products">
                      Shop
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                    <Link
                      className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                      to="#"
                      id="navbarDropdown"
                      role="button"
                      data-toggle="dropdown"
                      aria-haspopup="true"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      Learn
                    </Link>
                    <div
                      className="dropdown-menu"
                      aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"
                    >
                      <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                        Process
                      </Link>
                      <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                        About Us
                      </Link>
                      <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                        Blog
                      </Link>
                      <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                        News
                      </Link>
                      <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#">
                        Beyond The Bottle
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link
                      className="nav-link"
                      to="#"
                      data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#loginModal"
                    >
                      Login
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link
                      className="nav-link"
                      to="#"
                      data-toggle="modal"
                      data-target="#signupModal"
                    >
                      Sign Up
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <form className="dvSearch my-2 my-lg-0 px-3">
                  <input
                    className={`form-control border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 mr-sm-2 ${
                      window.innerWidth > 991 ? borderColor : ""
                    } ${location !== "/" ? "border-white" : ""} `}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    aria-label="Search"
                  />
                  <button className="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
                    <i
                      className={`fa fa-search ${iconColor} ${
                        location !== "/" ? "text-white" : ""
                      } `}
                    ></i>
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      }
      <div style={{ height: "10000px" }}></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

ACTIONS -

```
//ACTION CREATOR FETCH HOMEPAGE
export const fetchHomepage = () => {
  const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
  const url = `https://api.json-generator.com/templates/UhZ_20Akrr7T/data?access_token=${apiKey}`;
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.SET_HOMEPAGE,
      payload: data,
    });
  };
};

// remove homepage
export const removeHomepage = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.REMOVE_HOMEPAGE,
  };
};

//set nav bg color
export const setBgColor = (data) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.SET_NAV_BG_COLOR,
    payload: data,
  };
};
```

HOMEPAGE REDUCER-

```
import { actionTypes } from "../constants/action-types";

const homeiState = {
  data: {},
  bgColor: {},
  isLoading: true,
};
export const homepageReducer = (state = homeiState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_HOMEPAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: payload,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case actionTypes.REMOVE_HOMEPAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case actionTypes.SET_NAV_BG_COLOR:
      return {
        ...state,
        bgColor: payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency array is empty that's why your cleanup function is not running.

Answer (score -1):

The useEffect's cleanup function is only called before the component unmounts, your Header component is not unmounting, thus it will not be called.

If you want to call removeHomepage, I suggest calling it in the event function when clicking on a header item or creating a new useEffect hook that reacts to changes to a certain redux value.

Comment: I am clicking on the link which is in the header menu. then logically it should run cleanup function, but it doesn't and this is the issue or I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: The cleanup function only runs on unmounts, are you unmounting the header component?

Comment: When I click a header menu shop link then it goes to product page that means I am unmounting right? I am using functional components.